# Write out the "cell name" as a reult of IF Operator in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change the following code (array formula) in `Sheet2`

```
{=MAX(Sheet1!C2:H2-Sheet1!B2:G2)>0}
```

in this way that for the first True case, it writes the cell out.

```
{=IF(MAX(Sheet1!C2:H2-Sheet1!B2:G2)>0, in which cell the first case) }
```

For example in the pic
[image]

it happens in `D2`. I want to have as a result `D2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can u try with CELL("address")? It returns the cell address.I think that is required by u..